# Reduce glmer model size

Tags: r, lme4

I'm new to R and I'm using glmer to fit several binomial models and I only need them for calling `predict` to use the resulting probabilities. However, I have a very large dataset and the size of even just one model becomes extremely large:

```
> library(pryr)
> object_size(mod)
701 MB
```

The size of the coefficients of the model pales in comparison:

```
> object_size(coef(mod))
1.16 MB
```

As does the size of the fitted values:

```
> object_size(fitted(mod))
25.6 MB
```

First of all, I don't understand why the object size of the model is so large. It seems like it contains the original data frame used to fit the model, but even that doesn't account for the size. Why is it so huge?

Second, is it possible to strip the model down to only the parts needed to call predict? If so, how would I go about doing this? I found a post where this was done for `glm` at http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/reducing-your-r-memory-footprint-by-7000x.html but it seems that glmer models are accessed differently and have different components.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Digging into the model's internals:

```
> object_size(getME(mod, "X"))
205 MB
> object_size(getME(mod, "Z"))
36.9 MB
> object_size(getME(mod, "Zt"))
38.4 MB
> object_size(getME(mod, "Ztlist"))
41.6 MB
> object_size(getME(mod, "mmList"))
38.4 MB
> object_size(getME(mod, "y"))
3.2 MB
> object_size(getME(mod, "mu"))
3.2 MB
> object_size(getME(mod, "u"))
18.4 kB
> object_size(getME(mod, "b"))
19.5 kB
> object_size(getME(mod, "Gp"))
56 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "Tp"))
472 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "L"))
15.5 MB
> object_size(getME(mod, "Lambda"))
38.1 kB
> object_size(getME(mod, "Lambdat"))
38.1 kB
> object_size(getME(mod, "Lind"))
9.22 kB
> object_size(getME(mod, "Tlist"))
936 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "A"))
38.4 MB
> object_size(getME(mod, "RX"))
30.3 kB
> object_size(getME(mod, "RZX"))
1.05 MB
> object_size(getME(mod, "sigma"))
48 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "flist"))
4.89 MB
> object_size(getME(mod, "fixef"))
4.5 kB
> object_size(getME(mod, "beta"))
496 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "theta"))
472 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "ST"))
936 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "REML"))
48 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "is_REML"))
48 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "n_rtrms"))
48 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "n_rfacs"))
48 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "N"))
256 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "n"))
256 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "p"))
256 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "q"))
256 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "p_i"))
408 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "l_i"))
408 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "q_i"))
408 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "mod"))
48 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "m_i"))
424 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "m"))
48 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "cnms"))
624 B
> object_size(getME(mod, "devcomp"))
2.21 kB
> object_size(getME(mod, "offset"))
3.2 MB

> get_obj_size(mod@resp, "RC")
                       [,1]
family            673355488
initialize        673355488
initialize#lmResp 673355488
ptr               673355488
resDev            673355488
updateMu          673355488
updateWts         673355488
wrss              673355488
eta                 3196024
mu                  3196024
n                   3196024
offset              3196024
sqrtrwt             3196024
sqrtXwt             3196024
weights             3196024
wtres               3196024
y                   3196024
Ptr                      40
> get_obj_size(mod@pp, "RC")
                   [,1]
beta          449419408
initialize    449419408
initializePtr 449419408
ldL2          449419408
ldRX2         449419408
linPred       449419408
ptr           449419408
setTheta      449419408
sqrL          449419408
u             449419408
X             204549128
V             182171288
Ut             38448168
Zt             38448168
LamtUt         38353248
Xwts            3196024
RZX             1047176
Lambdat           38136
VtV               26192
delu              18408
u0                18408
Utr               18408
Lind               9224
beta0               496
delb                496
Vtr                 496
theta                72
Ptr                  40
```

Comment: This is a good question, but can we have a small-ish reproducible example please, or at least some information about the model dimensions (dimensions of model frame, number of fixed-effect coefficients, etc.?

Comment: Hey Ben,

Like I mentioned, I'm new to using R, so I hope this information is what you mean:

The size of the data frame used to fit the model is 399,498 rows by 14 columns. There are (I believe) 57 fixed effect coefficients, though I'm not totally sure how to get that. When I call `dim` on fixef(mod) it returns NULL, but just counting them there appear to be 57.

I can dig into it and get any information necessary, but I may need some pointers on how to access that information. Does it need the original data frame or can it be removed like it can be with glm?

Comment: Also, I would be interested in a reproducible example but I imagine this is too large for that purpose. Could it be done on the cbpp data?

Comment: for length of fixed coefficients I think you want `length(fixef(mod))` (it's not a matrix, so it doesn't have dimensions).

Comment: My eyeballing turned out to be exactly on the money: `length(fixef(mod))` yields 57 fixed coefficients. And my mistake, I didn't realize dim was the inappropriate choice here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting as an incomplete answer for now:

```
library("lme4")
gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
               data = cbpp, family = binomial)
library("pryr") 
object_size(gm1)  ## 505 kB
```

Following Steve Walker's S3/S4/Reference class dictionary for listing and extracting fields:

```
get_obj_size <- function(obj,type="S4") {
    fields <- switch(type,
                     S4=slotNames(obj),
                     RC=ls(obj))
    get_field <- switch(type,
                     S4=function(x) slot(obj,x),
                     RC=function(x) obj[[x]])
    field_list <- setNames(lapply(fields,get_field),fields)
    cbind(sort(sapply(field_list,object_size),decreasing=TRUE))
}
get_obj_size(gm1)
##           [,1]
## resp    356620  ## 'response module'
## pp      355420  ## 'predictor module'
## frame     6640
## optinfo   1748
## devcomp   1424
## call      1244
## flist     1232
## cnms       224
## u          152
## beta        56
## Gp          32
## lower       32
## theta       32
```

It will be worth further digging into the response and predictor modules to see what's there/what's big, with the caveats/complication that some information will be stored in the *environment* of those components

For example, I think that the whole slew of components that are nominally the same size are below are not actually independent, but have the same environment ...

```
get_obj_size(gm1@resp,"RC")
##                     [,1]
## initialize        356620
## initialize#lmResp 356620
## ptr               356620
## resDev            356620
## setOffset         356620
## updateMu          356620
## updateWts         356620
## wrss              356620
## family             26016
## eta                  472
## mu                   472
## n                    472
## offset               472
## sqrtrwt              472
## sqrtXwt              472
## weights              472
## wtres                472
## y                    472
## Ptr                   20
```

Another way to see what components are stored is to use `object_size(getME(model,component))` and iterate over the components listed via `eval(formals(getME)$name)`; this corresponds less precisely to the way the information is stored internally, but will give you an idea of how much space is required to hold (e.g.) the fixed-effect or random-effect model matrices.

I worked on this some more and have a partial solution, but there's still a lot stored that I can't seem to find/trim away of properly (**note** that this requires the latest version of `lme4` on Github: I had to modify the `predict` function slightly to weaken the dependence on internal structures).

```
glmer_chop <- function(object) {
    newobj <- object
    newobj@frame <- model.frame(object)[0,]
    newobj@pp <- with(object@pp,
                   new("merPredD",
                       Lambdat=Lambdat,
                       Lind=Lind,
                       theta=theta,
                       u=u,u0=u0,
                       n=nrow(X),
                       X=matrix(1,nrow=nrow(X)),
                       Zt=Zt)) ## .sparseDiagonal(n,shape="g")))
    newobj@resp <- new("glmResp",family=binomial(),y=numeric(0))
    return(newobj)
}
get_obj_size(environment(fm2@pp$initialize),"RC")
fm1 <- glmer(use ~ urban+age+livch+(1|district), Contraception, binomial)
object_size(Contraception)  ## 133 kB
object_size(fm1)  ## 1.05 MB
object_size(fm2 <- glmer_chop(fm1))  ## 699 kB
get_obj_size(fm2)          ## 'pp' is 547200 bytes
get_obj_size(fm2@pp,"RC")  ## 'initialize' object is 547200
saveRDS(fm2,file="tmp.rds")
fm2 <- readRDS("tmp.rds")
object_size(fm2)  ## 796 kB
rm(fm1)
pp <- predict(fm2,newdata=Contraception)
object_size(fm2) ## still 796K; no sharing
```

Note finally that `compare_size(fm2)` confirms that most of the information here is stored in environments, not in the object itself (but I don't know how `compare_size`/`object.size` deal with reference classes ...)

Comment: The ratios of what's taking up the most space seem similar to your example:


> get_obj_size(mod)
             [,1]
frame   695761408
call    673359304
resp    673355784
pp      449419704
flist     4894888
u           18408
devcomp      2208
optinfo      1488
cnms          624
beta          496
lower          72
theta          72
Gp             56


However, I'm having some trouble digging into the object itself:


> object_size(getME(mod, "resp"))
Error in match.arg(name) : 
  'arg' should be one of “X”, “Z”, ...

Sorry for the formatting here.

Comment: that should be e.g. `object_size(getME(mod,"X"))`

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood you initially. I updated my initial post with the results of the sizes of its components. Are the fixed and random effect coefficients held in fixef and u respectively? If so, those are minuscule compared to the rest of it.

Comment: Is there a version of this for lmer model fits?

Comment: And glmer_chop() doesn't work for me for glmer model fits. It returns "invalid formula".

Comment: Hello from the future. I found the glmer_chop function very helpful thank you @BenBolker.

Comment: glmer_chop can be modified for lmers. Just change the last line: "newobj@resp <- new('lmerResp', family = gaussian(), y=numeric(0))". Also, now works with the standard lme4 version.

Answer (score 0):

Is your concern about storage space or RAM? If it's about storage, one option would be to embed the call to estimate the model in the code that generates the predictions, so you never actually store the model object. Something like:

```
predictions <- predict(glmer(y ~ x, family = binomial), type = "response")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's about RAM. I need to have several models in memory at once, and my system completely chokes when I begin loading a few of these.

Comment: Ah, sorry, then I'm lost, too. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using the current lme-package version (1.1-31.1), the proposed answer from @BenBolker does unfortunately give wrong (different) results when using the predict()-function. One needs to include the "delu" object to fix this and have the same predictions as the original model object:

```
glmer_chop <- function(object) {
  newobj <- object
  newobj@frame <- model.frame(object)[0,]
  newobj@pp <- with(object@pp,
                    new("merPredD",
                        Lambdat=Lambdat,
                        Lind=Lind,
                        theta=theta,
                        #delu=delu,
                        u=u,u0=u0,
                        n=nrow(X),
                        X=matrix(1,nrow=nrow(X)),
                        Zt=Zt)) ## .sparseDiagonal(n,shape="g")))
  newobj@resp <- new("glmResp",family=binomial(),y=numeric(0))
  return(newobj)
}
```

(comment would have been sufficient, but I don't have enough reputation)